# No config files found in Logstash 1.4

Tags: file, config, logstash

I'm following the process on 
http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash

but even if I try to "logstash agent -f "D:\logstash.conf" with

```
input { stdin { } }
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

it return me an error:

Error: No config files found: D:\logstash.conf
Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file? and bla-bla-bla

I'm really confused.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need "agent". Also try slash instead of backslash. E.g. try logstash -f "D:/logstash.conf"

Comment: Thanks, backslash should be used.

Comment: You should accept an answer for this question.

Answer (score 9):

With Windows, you need to use forward slash "/" instead of the normal backslash "\" in the path to the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this issue: [File input - Windows style paths not supported](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-430)

Following syntax worked for me on logstash-1.4.2:

```
logstash agent -f   "C:/logstash-1.4.2/logstash-1.4.2/simple.conf"
```

Even this works:

```
logstash.bat agent -f   "C:/logstash-1.4.2/logstash-1.4.2/simple.conf"
```

Complete example of Using logstash with mongodb for Large scale log analysis(http://vaibhavtupe.blogspot.com/2014/11/using-logstash-for-large-scale-log.html)